# Turn non standard evaluation argument with spaces into a single string

Tags: r

I want to have a function that grabs the unquoted string from a single argument.  This works pretty well if there are no spaces in the non-standard evaluated argument.  But if there are it gives an error.  How can I pass an unquoted string to a function and have a single quoted character string come out the other side?  I suspect ldots may be a part of the solution or that this is a parse error and there's no way to do what I want to do.

## MWE

```
f <- function(x){
     deparse(substitute(x))

}

f(a)
## [1] "a"

f(a > b)
## [1] "a > b"

f(a b)
## Error: unexpected symbol in "f(a b"
```

## Desired ouput:

```
## [1] "a b"
```

Comment: Whether you want standard or non-standard evaluation, you still have to go through the R parser. What you type has to be valid R syntax and the syntax rules just don't allow spaces between symbol names passed to a function like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks:

```
f(`a b`)
#> [1] "a b"
```

Otherwise, the parser will (rightly) see that `a b` is not a valid R expression.

Comment: Of course this does allow to use NSE as requested by OP.  But if going to the trouble of typing backticks I can't help but think you may as well use quotes and standard evaluation. But I'm sure this as good as it gets if NSE is really required.

Comment: I think the answer here is indeed this is a parse error or like you said "not a valid R expression."